# Android webview doesn't show correctly in tablet

Tags: android, android-webview

I have 4.2.2 tablet and 6.0.1 telephone. When I show webview in tablet, it isn't correcly like below.

[image: tablet]

But Telephone is correct like below.

[image: telephone]

Layout's are same like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/layMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Code :

```
    private void startWebView(String url) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(KentRehberiActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Harita Getiriliyor...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     });
```

Why tablet's screen is not correct ?

Comment: Hello mobileprogramming, fill_parent is deprecated since API 8, change it to match_parent, maybe it could help. Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Hello. It don't be :(

Comment: The log says something?

Comment: nothing. It say everything is good

Comment: Kuchh to Log kahenge. Log ka kaam hai kehna..